# Why wont my timer function end? i cant get this function to return

Tags: c#, .net

Ok easy question..maybe.
Why wont this function end!!
I dont get the console.write Line('SSSSS') at the end of the program.
The timer runs out of time.
Should set running to false and kill the while loop.
But i doesnt. Just seem to get to the end of the EndTimer() function.
Do i need a Dispose or delete method?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace JuraCsharpPark3
{
    internal class Timer
    {
        public int TimeElapsed { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool TimerStarted { get; set; } = true;
        
        public Timer()
        {
            // Create timer instance
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new(interval: 1000);

            while (TimerStarted == true)
            {

                timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => HandleTimer();
                timer.Start();
                AlphaGame game = new AlphaGame();

            }

            void HandleTimer()
            {

                TimeElapsed++;
                Console.WriteLine(TimeElapsed);

                if (TimeElapsed > 10)
                {
                    EndTimer();
                    return;
                }
            }

            void EndTimer()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Out of Time!");
                TimerStarted = false;
                timer.Dispose();
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("SSSSSSS");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an endless loop! Just get rid of the `while` loop.

Comment: You need to debug your code, using breakpoints, etc.

Comment: @Jamiec, in theory, it's not endless. It keeps looping while `TimerStarted` is `true`, but that property is set to `false` in `EndTimer`, which should be executed after the `Elapsed` event is raised 10 times.

Comment: @jmcilhinney but in _practice_ it is endless.

Comment: The fact that you are registering an event handler inside a loop is a problem. That means that you're registering the same method to handle the same event over and over again. That's wrong. I'm not sure it's the root of the issue you've raised but it's definitely wrong.

Comment: @Jamiec, that's quite possible, but is removing the loop altogether the answer? The first two lines shouldn't be in a loop but we don't know what the third line does. Maybe it shouldn't be in a loop either or maybe it should. I'd probably lean towards the former, mind you.

Comment: I wonder how many times that manages to loop in the first second? I bet it's a lot! That's how many event subscriptions you will have.

Comment: Yes, removing the loop is the answer! https://dotnetfiddle.net/KoQQCc

Comment: Is the while loop intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding multiple event handlers in your loop.  Remove the handler and any other methods outside the loop and code will run as expected.

```
internal class Timer
{
    public  int TimeElapsed { get; set; } = 0;
    public  bool TimerStarted { get; set; } = true;

    public Timer()
    {
        // Create timer instance
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new (interval: 1000);
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => HandleTimer();
        timer.Start();
   
        AlphaGame game = new AlphaGame();

        while (TimerStarted == true) { }

        void HandleTimer()
        {
            TimeElapsed++;
            Console.WriteLine(TimeElapsed);

            if (TimeElapsed > 10)
            {
                EndTimer();
                return;
            }
        }

        void EndTimer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out of Time!");
            TimerStarted = false;
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SSSSSSS");
        return;
    }
}
```